# Does a 'D' visa count as a 'Schengen' visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, france, applications

I recently submitted an application to the French Embassy for a tourist ('C') visa. In the application form for "previous Schengen visas issued during the last 3 years", I did not mention my 'D' visa - issued by Switzerland (it was issued a week before this French visa application).

This is because on the Swiss Embassy's website, it listed the 'Schengen' visa as a short-stay 'C' visa and the 'D' visas as long-stay. So I thought only the visit visas mattered. However after applying I realised, it could be 'Schengen' in that it is issued by a Schengen state etc.

So I would just like to seek your opinions on this.

N.B. I applied for a 'C' visa as well since my validity date for the 'D' visa does not start that soon and I need a visa to enter Europe.

Comment: @GayotFow thanks for the info, was confused by it. either way, mistake's already made so i've sent them the amended form as well as a statement explaining my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a `D` visa is still a "Schengen visa". The Schengen agreement originally had `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` ones:

From [*The Schengen acquis*](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/uedocs/cmsUpload/SCH.ACQUIS-EN.pdf) (page 411):

> In  order  to  facilitate  matters  for  the  control  authorities, 
>   this  heading  specifies  the  type  of visa using the letters A, B, C
>   and D as follows :
>
> A: airport transit visa
>   B: transit visa
>   C: short-term visa
>   D: long-term national visa
>
> For visas with limited territorial validity and group visas the letters A, B or C shall be used depending on the case in question.

but `B` is now defunct.

Page 462 (ibid.) has a table of fees:

[image: table of fees]

where visa types are further differentiated. C3. and C4. may be referred to as "MEV" and all of `C` or just C1. and C2. as "uniform". Visas with limited territorial validity may be referred to as "LTV", visas issued at the border as "BCP" and airport transit visas as "ATV".

Comment: I see.. in that case should i email the embassy to inform them of my missing out the 'D' visa in the application form ? (I did mention the previous visit visas though). 

Since either way they'll see the 'D' visa in the passport

Comment: The A visa is still in use, too. They just did away with the B visa because they realized that C visas can bee used instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info, i've sent the amended form to the embassy. I just thought it was the 'C' visa as their webpages (both the French & Switzerland) embassies refer to short-stay visit visas as  "Schengen Visas" in their titles. 

Their long-stays are referred to as long-stay/national visas. So my confusion arose from that.

Comment: @woh32 your confusion is warranted. The D category is specified in the Schengen codes, but the conditions for issuing D visas are controlled by national law. But a D visa does authorize entry into and presence in other Schengen countries, subject to the 90/180 rule. So whether it's properly considered a "Schengen" visa isn't entirely clear.

Comment: @phoog yeah from what i understand too (please correct me if i'm wrong) the 'D' visas were given parity of movement not too long ago (<5/6 years?) 

either way best to be safe, if it's not necessary the embassy will inform me accordingly. I will update when they reply. Thanks for the help! :)